# getting history unique to a particular branch in svn

Tags: svn

In git you'd checkout the branch and do `git log` and the history that you'd see would be specific to that branch. Changes unique to other branches wouldn't show up in the `git log` command.

Is there a way to do this in SVN? ie. see the history of a specific branch whilst excluding changes unique to other branches.

Comment: That's what you normally get, unless you provide a path to an upper level directory :-?

Comment: If your working copy is pointing to a specific branch, then `svn log` will give you exactly what you're asking for. Is your working copy somewhere else? Are you pointing to the root containing all branches and the trunk and everything else? What are you seeing? What did you expect instead?

Answer (score 2):

`svn log URL_TO_BRANCH` will give you the full history of that branch, tracing all the way back to the origin of the path that the branch was created from.

If you have a working copy for that branch, `svn log` while in that directory will also give you the log, but if you haven't run svn update in a while you may miss some entries.